# How to adjust content to changing screen-size?

Tags: python, pygame, screen-size

I made my pygame window resizeable by using `pygame.RESIZEABLE` in `pygame.display.set_mode()` but now the content (buttons) I put on the screen earlier haven't shifted with the resizing which is expected but I cannot figure out a way to successfully implement this. I don't get any error messages thankfully. The only problem is that I am not getting the output I want. If the start button is at 100, 100 out of a screen of 600,600 I want it to be at 200,200 out of the resized screen which for this example I'm taking 1200,1200 for the sake of simplicity. I tried using percentages of the total screen size but that completely messed up the positioning.

```
import pygame

#Initializing pygane
pygame.init()

#Setting Screen Size
SCREENSIZE = (1000,700)
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE, pygame.RESIZABLE)


class Button():
def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
    ...

def draw(self, surface):
    ...

#create button instances
start_button = Button(100,100,start_img,0.8)
exit_button = Button(250,250,exit_img,0.8)
setting_button = Button(450,75,setting_img, 0.35)
```

Comment: Percentages seem like a reasonable approach. How were you calculating them?

Comment: *"I tried using percentages of the total screen size but that completely messed up the positioning."* - Why do you not show that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, it's pretty easy to do this with percentage size and position.

When the Button is first initialised, there is a given position and size.  But there is also a window size and position at startup too.  So instead of storing an exact `x` co-ordinate, instead we also store the *relative* `x` co-ordinate as a factor of the window width.

So say the window is `1000` pixels wide.  If your button is positioned in the exact middle, at pixel `500` - the relative position is:

```
initial_x (500) / initial_width (1000)  =>  0.5
```

So we're keeping that `relative_x` of `0.5`.  Any time we need to re-position the button, the new `x` will always be `relative_x * window_width` for any window size.  Bigger or smaller, it still works.

So say now the window is stretched to `1500` pixels wide.  The new `x` co-ordinate would be computer as:

```
relative_x (0.5) * window_width (1500) => 750
```

Which is obviously still right in the middle.  Say the window then shrunk to `300` pixels ~

```
relative_x (0.5) * window_width (300) => 150
```

Obviously you need to extend this further for the `y`, `width` and `height`.  But that is just more of the exact same thing.

Working example:

[image: animated_screen_shot]

Code:

```
import pygame

WINDOW_WIDTH = 600   # initial size only
WINDOW_HEIGHT= 300
MAX_FPS      = 60

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)


class StretchyButton( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A Button Sprite that maintains its relative position and size
        despite size changes to the underlying window.
        (Based on a pyGame Sprite, just to make drawing simpler) """
    def __init__( self, window, x, y, image ):
        super().__init__()
        self.original_image = image.convert_alpha()  # re-scaling the same image gets messed-up
        self.image = image
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
        # Calculate the relative size and position, so we can maintain our 
        # position & proportions when the window size changes
        # So "x_percent" is the relative position of the original x co-ord at the original size
        window_rect = window.get_rect()
        image_rect  = image.get_rect()
        # The given (x,y) of the button is relative to the initial window size.
        # Keep the ratios of the position against window size
        self.x_percent      = x / window_rect.width
        self.y_percent      = y / window_rect.height
        self.width_percent  = image_rect.width / window_rect.width
        self.height_percent = image_rect.height / window_rect.height

    def reScale( self, window ):
        """ When the window size changes, call this to re-scale the button to match """
        window_rect = window.get_rect()
        # re-calculate the button's position and size to match the new window size
        # we calcualted the percentage (relative) positions at startup, so now
        # they can just be used to re-position & re-size
        self.rect.x      = self.x_percent * window_rect.width
        self.rect.width  = self.width_percent * window_rect.width
        self.rect.y      = self.y_percent * window_rect.height
        self.rect.height = self.height_percent * window_rect.height
        # re-scale the button's image too
        # always re-scale off an original image, otherwise the image degrades
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.original_image, ( self.rect.width, self.rect.height ) )



### I don't like the look of text without some surrounding space
def renderWithBorder( font, text, border=3, foreground=WHITE, background=BLACK ):
    """ Render the given text with the given font, but surrounded by a border of pixels """
    text = font.render( text, True, foreground, background )
    width,height = text.get_rect().size
    bigger_surf = pygame.Surface( ( width + border + border, height + border + border ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
    bigger_surf.fill( background )
    bigger_surf.blit( text, ( border, border ) )
    return bigger_surf


###
### MAIN
###
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Stretchy Buttons" )

font = pygame.font.Font( None, 30 )

# Just a re-square image
red_box = pygame.Surface( ( 64, 64 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
red_box.fill( RED )

# create a set of buttons
butt0 = StretchyButton( window,  10,  10, red_box )
butt1 = StretchyButton( window, 200, 100, renderWithBorder( font, "The Owl" ) )
butt2 = StretchyButton( window, 200, 150, renderWithBorder( font, "And The Pussycat" ) )
butt3 = StretchyButton( window, 200, 200, renderWithBorder( font, "Went to Sea" ) )

# use a sprite group to hold the buttons, because it's quicker
buttons = pygame.sprite.Group()
buttons.add( [ butt0, butt1, butt2, butt3 ] )

running = True
while running:
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()   # used to govern the max MAX_FPS
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            # The window size has changed, re-scale our buttons
            #new_width, new_height = event.size
            for butt in buttons:
                butt.reScale( window )

    # paint the window
    window.fill( WHITE )
    buttons.draw( window )

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick( MAX_FPS )   # keep the frame-rate sensible, don't waste electricity
```