# Python pygame score on screen

Tags: python

I am new to Pygame but have some python experience from before. I am trying to get the score displayed on the screen, while the player plays the game but for some reason I can't get it to work. I have provided my code below and would request help with the same.

```py
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

pygame.init()

LANE_WIDTH = 150
NUM_LANES = 3

Score_value = 0
textX = 10
textY = 10

CAR_WIDTH = 160
CAR_HEIGHT = 100
CAR_SPEED = 5

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080

lane_positions = [(SCREEN_HEIGHT - NUM_LANES * LANE_WIDTH) // 2 + x * LANE_WIDTH for x in range(NUM_LANES)]
middle_line_positions = [lane + LANE_WIDTH // 2 for lane in lane_positions]

player = pygame.Rect(600, (SCREEN_HEIGHT - CAR_HEIGHT) // 2, 35, 50)


wall = pygame.Rect(-100, 0, 100, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
cars = []

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

run = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def show_score(textX, textY):
    score_text = font.render("Score: " + str(Score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score_text, (textX, textY))


def spawn_car():
    lane_index = random.randint(0, NUM_LANES - 1)
    lane_y = lane_positions[lane_index]
    new_car = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH, lane_y + (LANE_WIDTH - CAR_HEIGHT) // 2, CAR_WIDTH, CAR_HEIGHT)
    for car in cars:
        if car.colliderect(new_car):
            return  # Don't spawn if there's a collision
    cars.append(new_car)
    return

while run:
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    show_score(textX, textY)
    


    # Draw the lanes
    for lane_y, middle_line_y in zip(lane_positions, middle_line_positions):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, lane_y), (SCREEN_WIDTH, lane_y), 4)

    # Draw white line for the bottom lane
    bottom_lane_y = lane_positions[NUM_LANES - 1]
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, bottom_lane_y + LANE_WIDTH), (SCREEN_WIDTH, bottom_lane_y + LANE_WIDTH), 4)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), player)

    # Draw grass
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 0), pygame.Rect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, lane_positions[0]))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 0), pygame.Rect(0, lane_positions[NUM_LANES - 1] + LANE_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    # Move and draw each car
    for car in cars:
        car.move_ip(-CAR_SPEED, 0)  # Increase the movement amount to make cars go faster
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), car)

        # Check if the car collides with the player
        if car.colliderect(player):
            run = False

        # Check if the car collides with the wall
        if car.colliderect(wall):
            cars.remove(car)

    # Spawn a new car randomly
    if random.random() < 0.02:  # Adjust the probability to your liking
        spawn_car()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[K_UP]:
        player.move_ip(0, -5)
    elif key[K_DOWN]:
        player.move_ip(0, 5)

    Score_value += 1
    
    show_score(textX, textY)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"...  for some reason I cant get it to work"*? The score is displayed nicely, the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: I now see that my problem was me beaing stupid and settering the screen size higher then my laptop reselution. @Rabbid76

Comment: So it is not a programming issue and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259470/how-to-adjust-content-to-changing-screen-size,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with your window size. I resized the window and the score started showing up. It seems like the reason the score wasn't showing up earlier was because the font was being rendered outside of the screen itself, due to the window size being too big.

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
```

Here I have set the window size to be `(800, 600)` but the same can be customized as per requirement.

---

**NOTE:** The code provided will still work without any issues, in devices with a screen size big enough to render the font within itself.

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Auto-resizing window**

Furthermore, if you want the game to be cross-compatible with multiple window types and want the window size to be adjusted based on the screen size you can use the `pygame.display.get_desktop_sizes()` method to get a list of the screen sizes of all active desktops, and multiply it with aspect ratio to get your desired window size.

```
import pygame

pygame.init() # to use pygame.display.set_desktop_sizes() its important to initialize pygame first.

def get_compatible_window_size(aspect_ratio) :
    height_multiplier = 1 / (1 + aspect_ratio)
    width_multiplier = 1 - height_multiplier
    # Currently selects the first active desktop detected. But this method
    # can be further customized to find the smallest screen size.
    screen_size = pygame.display.get_desktop_sizes()[0]
    win_width, win_height = screen_size[0] * width_multiplier, screen_size[1] * height_multiplier
    return win_width, win_height

win_size = get_compatible_window_size(1920/1080)
```